# Export the return value of chain promise

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, axios, es6-promise

**How to export the returned value of a multiple promise.** I need to export both data from first API to second API data. Which means insert first data to an array and also the second then return that array and export to use from another .js file.

I tried to search on how can I returned the value inside then() method. But when I call the imported file into another .js file it logs *[Promise, Promise, Promise...]*

**API.js**

```
function getAllData(url) {
    return axios.get(url, {
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
        }
    }).then(response => response.data.d.results);
}

function getAllDataVHistory(data) {

    return data.map(i => axios.get(`urltwo?getID${i.Id}`).then(response => {
        return response.data;
    }));
}

export const final = () =>
    getAllData(`urlone`)
    .then(data => getAllDataVHistory(data));
```

**Display.js**

```
import {
   final
} from "./API.js";

final().then(en => {
    // return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    //   if (true) {
    //    return resolve(console.log(en));
    //   } else {
    //    return reject("promise failed");
    //   }
    // });
   console.log(en);
});
```

***Console.log result***

```
(3) [Promise, Promise, Promise]
```

Comment: even if I removed return new Promise still it logs (3) [Promise, Promise, Promise], @TheReason

Comment: Without [top-level await](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await), you cannot export the result value but only the promise. Just wait for the promise in the file that imports your module.

Comment: You want to use `Promise.all` on your array of promises

Comment: But I need to use the data of the first API because the id is in the first API like, `data.map(i => axios.get(`urltwo?getID${i.Id}`)` @Bergi

Comment: @junreyd Getting the data from the first API and passing it into the second is already working. Your problem is only the array of promises within `getAllDataVHistory`.

Comment: Yes can you give me example how Promise.all works to my code? @Bergi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> return data.map(i => axios.get(`urltwo`)
> ```

This is going to return an *array of promises*

Since you are resolving a promise with that, you are going to get that array (hence what you see in the logs).

You need to return a *single* promise so it will be adopted.

[Use `Promise.all(array_of_promises)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to create a single promise that will resolve when all the promises in the array have resolved.

Comment: But I need to communicate `urlone` and `urltwo` API. To pass the id from `urlone` to `urltwo` before I call the `urltwo` I need first to get id from `urlone`. just like - `data.map(i => axios.get(`urltwo?getID${i.Id}`)`

Comment: @junreyd — So? That all happens before your problem.